# Regarding REST response and XMLElement

Tags: java, xml, rest, xml-parsing, jaxb

I have below a REST response which needs to be created in the code:

```
<sample>
   <tags> 
       <tag>
           <name>ABC</name>
           <Date>2014-10-14T12:30:05Z</ingress>
       </tag>
       <tag>
           <name>DEF</name>
           <Date>2014-10-14T12:30:05Z</ingress>
       </tag>
   </tags>
</sample>
```

However,I am getting

```
<sample>
    <tags>           
        <name>ABC</name>
        <Date>2014-10-14T12:30:05Z</ingress>
    </tags>
    <tags>
        <name>DEF</name>
        <Date>2014-10-14T12:30:05Z</ingress>        
    </tags>
</sample>
```

in the response.Can someone please help me how  the declaration of Java class to get the desired REST response ?

Here is the java code:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "sample")
public class Sample {
    private List<Tag> tags;

    @XmlElement(name = "tags")
    public List<Tag> getTags() {
        return tags;
    }

    /**
     * @param tags
     *            the tags to set
     */
    public void setTags(List<Tag> tags) {
        this.tags = tags;
    }

}

@XmlRootElement(name = "tag")
public class Tag {
    private String name;
    private Date date;

    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    @XmlElement(name = "name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * @param name
     *            the name to set
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * @return the date
     */
    @XmlElement(name = "date")
    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    /**
     * @param date
     *            the date to set
     */
    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Please post the java code.

Comment: Here is the Java Code:

Comment: There must be other code which actually create `Tag/Tags` and marshalls that. Post that code too.

Comment: These are REST response.So I think jersey takes care of that.

Answer (score 3):

```
@XmlElement(name = "tags")
List<Tag> tags;
```

It basically reads, for each item in the list, create a element named `<tags>`. So in essence, all you have is a `<subject>` element wrapping multiple `<tags>`.

A couple options to get another "upper-level" element

You can create a "upper-level" class to represent that, say `Tags`

```
public class Tags {
    protected List<Tag> tags;

    @XmlElement(name = "tag")
    public List<Tag> getTags() {
        if (tags == null) {
            tags = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        return tags;
    }

    public void setTags(List<Tag> tags) {
        this.tags = tags;
    }
}
```

Then have an instance of `Tags` as a property of `Sample`

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "sample")
public class Sample {
    private Tags tags;

    @XmlElement(name = "tags")
    public void setTags(Tags tags) {
        this.tags = tags;
    }

    public Tags getTags() {
        return tags;
    }
}
```

**OR**

An even simpler solution is just to use [`@XmlElementWrapper`](https://jaxb.java.net/nonav/2.2.3/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElementWrapper.html)

> Generates a wrapper element around XML representation. This is primarily intended to be used to produce a wrapper XML element around collections

Using your original code, you can simple add the annotation to the list

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "sample")
public class Sample {
   private List<Tag> tags;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "tags")
    @XmlElement(name = "tag")
    public List<Tag> getTags() {
        if (tags == null) {
            tags = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        return tags;
    }

    public void setTags(List<Tag> tags) {
        this.tags = tags;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the `@XmlElementWrapper` annotation to add a grouping element to your collection.

```
@XmlElementWrapper
@XmlElement(name = "tag")
public List<Tag> getTags() {
    return tags;
}
```

**Note:**  `@XmlElement` applies to each item in the collection.